# Is it possible to call Objective c view controller class from swift class using storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

Is possible to push objective c view controller from swift class file?

I tried as mentioned below,

```
import UIKit
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
 class func instantiate() -> DashboardViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashboardView", bundle: Bundle.main)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboardVC") as! DashboardViewController
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func userClickedSubmitButton(_ sender: Any) {
  //let dashboardDetailsVC = DashboardDetailsViewController.instantiate()  
  //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboardDetailsVC!, animated: true)

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashboardDetails", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashDetails") as! DashboardDetailsViewController
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Getting error as "Use of undeclared type 'DashboardDetailsViewController'". I tried importing class file even. Is there any work around to resolve this? TIA.

Comment: have you tried using bridging header?

Comment: I totally forgot to add my header in brining header class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file `"ModuleName-Bridging-Header.h"` and in this file 
`import "YourObjectiveCViewController.h"` and then try opening it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user579911 If my solution solves your problem you can upvote and mark it as answer. Thanks